# hadoop - map/reduce functionality

Tags: hadoop

I just started looking into the hadoop and made the wordcount example work on a cluster(two datanodes) after going through some struggles.

But I have a question about Map/Reduce functionality. I read that during map, the input files/data is transformed into another form of data that can be efficiently processed during the reduce step.

Let's say that I have four input files(input1.txt, input2.txt, input3.txt, input4.txt) and want to read input files and transform into another form of data for reduce.

So here is the question. If I run the application (wordcount) on a cluster environment (two datanodes), are these four input files read on each datanode or two input files read on each datanode?  And how can I check which file is read on which datanode?

Or does map(on each datanode) read files as some kind of block instead of reading an individual file?

Answer (score 0):

See hadoop works on basis of blocks rather than files. So even if all the four files are less than 128MB(or 64MB depending on block size) than they will be read by only one mapper. This chunk which is read by mapper is also known as InputSplit. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Does it mean that if the block size is large(maybe more than 500MB), blocks are read by mapper(submitted to two datanodes)?

Answer (score 0):

files are divided into blocks. blocks are spread on the data nodes in the cluster. blocks are also replicated by replication factor (default 3) so each block can be on multiple nodes. scheduler decides where to run mapper which depends on which data node is available to process and where the data is located (data locality comes into picture). in your program (wordcount) each line is fed to a mapper (not whole file or block) one by one.